# How to Split attribute tables into new records (Data Management)

Tags: file-geodatabase, query, table, data-management

(Arcgis user)
I created a fgdb for inspections in the Esri Collector app.

How can i create a export table of the feature that splits the fieldnames into seperated records related to fieldname Code?

My Example:

[image]

Some ideas to create the table?

Comment: What you want to do is somewhat similar to the [Pivot Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm) command.  You can probably get there with some modification of your table.  Perhaps adding and filling new fields that would then allow to pivot the results to a new table.

Comment: Upon further reflection, you are almost doing a reverse pivot.

Comment: It isn't in ArcGIS, but this answer explains exactly what you need to do.  This is from the Superuser forum.  http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel#78464

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer.

The transpose tool

[image]

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/transpose-fields.htm